# correcting FB meta tags

Tags: facebook, metadata, social-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)
>   [Facebook share url thumbnail problem](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4967979/facebook-share-url-thumbnail-problem)

I discovered, after testing, that I had the wrong meta tags for image or url. After correcting the information on my webpage, FB still seems to reflect the old information. Is there something I can do to correct this? Or does FB just take a certain length of time to kick in and if so, how long?

Comment: From experience it eventually resolves itself (24 hrs).

Answer (score 2):

Changing the tags should be enough, but there are some tags that aren't allowed to change past certain limits (check here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ under "Editing Meta Tags"). You can use the linter tool to check that your tags are correct, or see, if they are wrong - why they are wrong:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug